# Rxjava booleanSupplier expected

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Hi i am trying to poll a request using rxjava repeatUntil but getting some error on it

below is my code

```
accountDelegator.signUpReady(signUpRequest)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .repeatUntil { response -> 
                    if (response.isSuccesfull){
                        return onComplete()
                    }
            }
```

it says it requires a booleanSupplier not a unit?

i am simply trying to repeat the request above until i get a response.isSuccessful  and then returning onComplete() as in the rxjava docs it states that to exit a repeatUntil observer, you have to call onComplete

Comment: onComplete() return type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`repeatUntil` does not provide any items to its `BooleanSupplier` function which function is expected to indicate whether or not to repeat the upstream. To "exit" it, you have to return `true` from the function as you can't call `onComplete` on anything there (nor does it make sense, you likely misinterpreted the documentation).

You could instead use `filter` and `take` which can be used to stop an otherwise repeating sequence:

```
accountDelegator.signUpReady(signUpRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .repeat(/* 100 */)
            .filter { response -> response.isSuccessful }
            .take(1)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

You'd also want to limit the number of retries and/or delay the repetition by some time (so that your code doesn't spam the server just to not succeed) via `repeatWhen`.

**Edit**

To detail the last sentence about delayed retries, here is a way of doing that:

```
.repeatWhen { completion -> completion.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
```

instead of `repeat(100)`. When the upstream completes, an object is signalled through `completion` which is then delayed by 1 seconds. After that, the other side in `repeatWhen` receives the object which triggers a resubscription to the upstream.

Comment: typo. should be .filter{response -> response.isSuccessful} curley brace?

Comment: I can never know how Kotlin will interact with SAM types, especially since it depends on your Kotlin version. Try with and without the outer brace.

Comment: tried with bracket and doesnt work, needs curley braces. also it seems that it literely fires n number of requests without actually waiting for a response for each one? how do i delay each request?

Comment: Ok cool i will give this a go. If i replace the repeat(n) times with repeatWhen. Does it keep on going forever and i will have to manually exit the loop? how would i do that? ideally i want to do it once response.IsSuccesful is true